# Symfony2 Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, templates, symfony

I am developing an application using Symfony2 and twig for the templates. I am also using ajax. This is part of my code in my controller:

```
    public function testuaanotatuAction(Request $request)
    { 
      if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
      {
       return $this->forward('AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle:Page:Interpretatu');
      }

    // Some code.....
            return $this->render('AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle:Page:AnotatuInterpretazio.html.twig',
                                   array('Azpimarratu' => $Markagarria->getMarkIdent()));

}


    public function InterpretatuAction()
    {
      return $this->render('AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle:Page:FAQ.html.twig');
    }
```

And then this is my code in AnotatuInterpretazio.html.twig' were I do the Ajax call using JQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
          $("#ButtonId").click(function () 
                             {
                               $.ajax({
                                        url: "{{ path('AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle_testuaanotatu') }}",
                                        type: "POST"
                                       });      
                         });
    </script>
```

As you can see what I intend to do here is to call InterpretatuAction through the template AnotatuInterpretazio.html.twig. Then InterpretatuAction will call another template. It doesnt work, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `.success` function in your code. If you don't, nothing is going to happen

Comment: And what do I have to do,what can I do, inside the success function? I s it really necesary?

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation, everything is explained http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that JavaScript can't resolve the method `path()`, this method is useful only in the server side for twig.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `path()`, always that you are in a twig template (although you are in a script) inside `{{ }}`.
It would be something similar like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('usuario_logout') }}">Cerrar sesión</a>
```

This code is part of one of my projects and it's working.